# Make it explode!

Tags: code-golf, matrix

Take a matrix of positive integers as input, and **make it explode!**

---

The way you explode a matrix is by simply adding zeros around every element, including the outside borders.

Input/output formats are optional as always!

#### Test cases:

```
1
-----
0 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 0
--------------

1 4
5 2
-----
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 4 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 5 0 2 0
0 0 0 0 0
--------------

1 4 7
-----
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 4 0 7 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
--------------

6
4
2
-----
0 0 0
0 6 0
0 0 0
0 4 0
0 0 0
0 2 0
0 0 0
```

Answer (score 59):

## [Operation Flashpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Flashpoint:_Cold_War_Crisis) scripting language, 182 bytes

```
f={t=_this;c=count(t select 0);e=[0];i=0;while{i<c*2}do{e=e+[0];i=i+1};m=[e];i=0;while{i<count t}do{r=+e;j=0;while{j<c}do{r set[j*2+1,(t select i)select j];j=j+1};m=m+[r,e];i=i+1};m}
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
f=
{
  // _this is the input matrix. Let's give it a shorter name to save bytes.
  t = _this;
  c = count (t select 0);

  // Create a row of c*2+1 zeros, where c is the number of columns in the
  // original matrix.
  e = [0];
  i = 0;
  while {i < c*2} do
  {
    e = e + [0];
    i = i + 1
  };

  m = [e]; // The exploded matrix, which starts with a row of zeros.
  i = 0;
  while {i < count t} do
  {
    // Make a copy of the row of zeros, and add to its every other column 
    // the values from the corresponding row of the original matrix.
    r = +e;
    j = 0;
    while {j < c} do
    {
      r set [j*2+1, (t select i) select j];
      j = j + 1
    };

    // Add the new row and a row of zeroes to the exploded matrix.
    m = m + [r, e];
    i = i + 1
  };

  // The last expression is returned.
  m
}
```

**Call with:**

```
hint format["%1\n\n%2\n\n%3\n\n%4",
    [[1]] call f,
    [[1, 4], [5, 2]] call f,
    [[1, 4, 7]] call f,
    [[6],[4],[2]] call f];
```

**Output:**

[image]

**In the spirit of the challenge:**

[image]

Comment: Unknown; man; one thousand.

Comment: Now I'm confused

Comment: @MrGrj The command literally makes something blow up

Comment: +1 for the second gif "_In the spirit of the challenge_"! :)

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>12</s>  11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 byte thanks to Erik the Outgolfer (no need to use swapped arguments for a join)

```
j00,0jµ€Z$⁺
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/LwEDHIOvQ1kdNa6JUHjXu@v//f3S0oY5JrE60qY5RbCwA)** Or see a [test suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/LwEDHIOvQ1kdNa6JUHjXu@n90z@F2IMcbioEoEoizHjXuO7Tt0Lb//6O5FKKjDWNjdcC0jkmsTrSpjhGCr2MOZZsBZUCyQDmuWAA).

A monadic link accepting and returning lists of lists.

#### How?

```
j00,0jµ€Z$⁺ - Link: list of lists, m
          ⁺ - perform the link to the left twice in succession:
         $  -   last two links as a monad
      µ€    -     perform the chain to the left for €ach row in the current matrix:
j0          -       join with zeros                [a,b,...,z] -> [a,0,b,0,...,0,z]
  0,0       -       zero paired with zero = [0,0]
     j      -       join                     [a,0,b,0,...,0,z] -> [0,a,0,b,0,...,0,z,0]
        Z   -     and then transpose the resulting matrix
```

Comment: You can save a byte: `j00,0jµ€Z$⁺`

Comment: Oh, of course, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 38 bytes

```hs
a%l=a:(=<<)(:[a])l
f l=(0%)<$>(0<$l)%l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcE7DoAgDADQ3VN0gKQkDP4mUrxI06GDRGIlRr0/vnfoe@5mvau3rAkzUcDEKsGGApZx9IHchiM5C976pbVBhvup7QMHBZinOEvkJa4i/Qc)

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
FTXdX*0JQt&(
```

Input is a matrix with `;` as row separator.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3y0kIiVCy8ArsERN4///aEMFE2sFUwWjWAA)

#### Explanation

```
FT     % Push [0 1]
Xd     % Matrix with that diagonal: gives [0 0; 0 1]
X*     % Implicit input. Kronecker product
0      % Push 0
JQt    % Push 1+j (interpreted as "end+1" index) twice
&(     % Write a 0 at (end+1, end+1), extending the matrix. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 18 bytes

```
Ov"y ®î íZ c p0Ã"²
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=T3YieSCu7iDtWiBjIHAwwyKy&input=WwpbMSAyIDNdCls0IDUgNl0KWzcgOCA5XQpdIC1R) (Uses the `-Q` flag so the output is easier to understand.)

Similar to the Jelly answer, but a whole lot longer...

#### Explanation

The outer part of the code is just a workaround to simulate Jelly's `⁺`:

```
  "             "²   Repeat this string twice.
Ov                   Evaluate it as Japt.
```

The code itself is:

```
y ®   î íZ c p0Ã
y mZ{Zî íZ c p0}   Ungolfed
y                  Transpose rows and columns.
  mZ{          }   Map each row Z by this function:
     Zî              Fill Z with (no argument = zeroes).
        íZ           Pair each item in the result with the corresponding item in Z.
           c         Flatten into a single array.
             p0      Append another 0.
```

Repeated twice, this process gives the desired output. The result is implicitly printed.

Answer (score 5):

### [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 12 bytes

```
₁₁
Tm»o:0:;0
```

Takes and returns a 2D integer array. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1FTIxBxheQe2p1vZWBlbfD////oaEMdIx3jWJ1oEx1THbPYWAA)

### Explanation

Same idea as in many other answers: add zeroes to each row and transpose, twice.
The row operation is implemented with a fold.

```
₁₁         Main function: apply first helper function twice
Tm»o:0:;0  First helper function.
 m         Map over rows:
  »         Fold over row:
   o         Composition of
      :       prepend new value and
    :0        prepend zero,
       ;0    starting from [0].
            This inserts 0s between and around elements.
T          Then transpose.
```

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, 39 bytes

```
r=Riffle[#,0,{1,-1,2}]&/@Thread@#&;r@*r
```

[Try it at the Wolfram sandbox!](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/) Call it like "`r=Riffle[#,0,{1,-1,2}]&/@Thread@#&;r@*r@{{1,2},{3,4}}`".

Like many other answers, this works by transposing and riffling zeros in each row then doing the same thing again. Inspired by Jonathan Allan's [Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128270/66104) specifically, but only because I happened to see that answer first.

Answer (score 4):

## Dyalog APL, 24 bytes

*4 bytes saved thanks to @ZacharyT*

*5 bytes saved thanks to @KritixiLithos*

```
{{⍵↑⍨-1+⍴⍵}⊃⍪/,/2 2∘↑¨⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24Tq6ke9Wx@1TXzUu0LXUMFQ@1HvFqBA7aOu5ke9q/R19I0UjB51zAAqOLQCJA7UpGDIpW6rzgWkFYwUjKFsoGJkLkgXyKDNJlABYwUTiIAlAA)

Comment: You don't need parens around the `1,1,⍴⍵`, do you?

Comment: I get this: [`{{⍵↑⍨-1 1+⍴⍵}⊃⍪/,/2 2∘↑¨⍵}`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24Tq6ke9Wx@1TXzUu0LXUMFQ@1HvFqBA7aOu5ke9q/R19I0UjB51zAAqOLQCJA7UpGDIpW6rzgWkFYwUjKFsoGJkLkgXyKDNJlABYwUTiIAlAA) at 26

Comment: @KritixiLithos nice use of `1 1+`!

Comment: APL's array oriented, so would `1+` work?

Comment: @ZacharyT I just realised that after seeing your answer...

Comment: Why did you rollback the edit?

Comment: @KritixiLithos cos he posted an answer resembling it (with `¯1-` instead of `-1+`)

Comment: I'm fine if you want to use the 24 byte solution you had.

Comment: @ZacharyT I think any train would make a lot longer than the dfn, because of the `⍪/,/`.

Comment: Yeah, kept running into that.

Comment: You can just use `0⍪0,`

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>104 101 97 93</s> 86 bytes

- @Zachary T saved 3 bytes: unused variable `w` removed and one unwanted space
- @Zachary T saved yet another 4 bytes: `[a,b]` as just `a,b` while appending to a list
- @nore saved 4 bytes: use of slicing
- @Zachary T and @ovs helped saving 7 bytes: squeezing the statements in for loop

```python
def f(a):
 m=[(2*len(a[0])+1)*[0]]
 for i in a:r=m[0][:];r[1::2]=i;m+=r,m[0]
 return m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY27DsMgDADn@is8QsJQ6CMSEV9ieUAqUZEKiSw69Ospme50yx2/9t7rrfdX2nBTUXvAEki56ZOqinRlPVs9DTLgtgtmzBWjl1BGI8@rkPXecchrmYOYMwNKal@pWHoMBBeyxpkHm2GLuZsnA8MhuTZ1HnX/Aw)

Comment: You can remove `w` and save 2 bytes: https://repl.it/JBPE

Comment: Oh, you have an unneeded space after the line `m+=[r,w]`

Comment: Also, can you save 4 bytes by changing `[j,0]` to `j,0` and `[r,m[0]` to `r,m[0]`?

Comment: You can save a 4 other bytes using [array slices](https://tio.run/##JU27CsQgEKxvv2JLTVLEpBP8kmUL4ZQIpwmLV9zXmw3XzIsZ5vr142z7GO@UMZtoPWANZLbpk5qJtLKdnZ2UGTCfggVLw6gtlFA1Js@PJuf9xhiwqKtzIFnqfySpf6VhHTEQvMjxorgzMFxSWjfPqR03 "Python 3 – Try It Online").

Comment: You can save three bytes by converting to python2 and changing the `for` loop indentation to a single tab.

Comment: I was just about to do that. :)

Comment: Listen to `ovs`'s suggestion!

Comment: I suggest switching to Python 2 and using `print m` instead of `return m` to save 1 byte.

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, 41 bytes

```matlab
@(M)resize(kron(M,[0 0;0 1]),2*size(M)+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQcNXsyi1OLMqVSO7KD9Pw1cn2kDBwNpAwTBWU8dICyzhq6ltqPk/Ma9YI1pPT4/LUMGIy1TBLFbzPwA)

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 118 bytes

```
def a(b):
    z='00'*len(b[0])+'0'
    r=z+'\n'
    for c in b:
        e='0'
        for d in c:e+=str(d)+'0'
        r+=e+'\n'+z+'\n'
    return r
```

First time golfing! Not the best, but I'm quite proud if I can say so myself!

- -17 bytes from Wheat comments
- -4 bytes from inlining the second for loop

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site.  You seem to have a good deal of whitespace here.  For instance some of your `+=` and `=` are surrounded by spaces, which can be removed.  In addition doing `+=` twice in a row could be simplified into a single statement, for example `e+=str(d)+'0'`

Comment: @WheatWizard: Thanks and thanks. Saved 17 bytes :)

Comment: I'm now noticing that you can collapse your inner `for` loop onto a single line `for d in c:e+=str(d)+'0'`, but you might want to go with a join map(str,d))+'0'`, in which case it becomes pointless to define `e` at all.

Comment: Since my last comment may have been a bit all over the place [Here is the golf I had in mind](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFRI0nTiksBCKps1Q0M1LVyUvM0kqINYjW11Q3UwRJFtlXa6jF5EE5afpFCskJmnkKSVZE2UIc6SJleVn5mnkZuYoFGcUmRTrImSC9QgzaSvqLUktKiPIWi//8B "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Ah, just thought of that myself! Hmm, I'll have to learn what .join and map() is first I guess. I'll be back!

Comment: `join` is a very useful tool to know for python golfing, `map` is a little less useful because it can often be replaced with a list comprehension in less bytes.

Comment: You can put the definitions of `z` and `r` on the same line (with a `;` between them), saving a byte of indentation.

Answer (score 3):

### R, 65 bytes

Thanks to Jarko Dubbeldam and Giuseppe for very valuable comments!

Code

```
f=function(x){a=dim(x);y=array(0,2*a+1);y[2*1:a[1],2*1:a[2]]=x;y}
```

Input for the function must be a matrix or two dimensional array.

Test

```
f(matrix(1))
f(matrix(c(1,5,4,2),2))
f(matrix(c(1,4,7),1))
f(matrix(c(6,4,2)))
```

Output

```
> f(matrix(1))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    0
> f(matrix(c(1,5,4,2),2))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    4    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    5    0    2    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
> f(matrix(c(1,4,7),1))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    4    0    7    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
> f(matrix(c(6,4,2)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    6    0
[3,]    0    0    0
[4,]    0    4    0
[5,]    0    0    0
[6,]    0    2    0
[7,]    0    0    0
```

Comment: At a glance I think using `a=dim(x)*2+1` instead of `nrow` and `ncol` would be better. You could then do `y=matrix(0);dim(y)=a` and `2*1:a[1],2*1:a[2]`.

Comment: Actually `y=array(0,a)` would be even shorter.

Comment: I believe you can remove the parentheses around the indices, i.e., `2*1:a[1]` because `:` has higher precedence than `*`

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 64 bytes

```python
lambda l:map(g,*map(g,*l))
g=lambda*l:sum([[x,0]for x in l],[0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHHKjexQCNdRwtK5WhqcqXbQiS1cqyKS3M1oqMrdAxi0/KLFCoUMvMUcmJ1og1iNf/n2EZHG@oY6RgD@SY6pjpmsbFcBUWZeSUKaRo5mv8B)

The function `g` intersperses the input between zeroes. The main function transposes the input while applying `g`, then does so again. Maybe there's a way to avoid the repetition in the main function.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 55 bytes

```
(a=ArrayFlatten)@{o={0,0},{0,a@Map[{{#,0},o}&,#,{2}]}}&
```

Comment: `o={0,0}` can be reduced to `o=0{,}`

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 98 bytes

Input as 2D array, Output as string

```php
<?foreach($_GET as$v)echo$r=str_pad(0,(count($v)*2+1)*2-1," 0"),"
0 ".join(" 0 ",$v)." 0
";echo$r;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYyxCsIwGIT3PEU4MqQaS1J0isVJfAG3EEqIldShCW319eOPLsfH3ceVVOr5UlJhYrhd771zMFA4wiuHE1EH72195mUMMcmfxMMqPs0YUxZLv27LUMJDaiVjfs@bpGnX7Q3FwShwjUaBaY72ladZUsGhyGmJGOz/xdb6BQ)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 116 bytes

Input and Output as 2D array

```php
<?foreach($_GET as$v){$r[]=array_fill(0,count($v)*2+1,0);$r[]=str_split("0".join(0,$v)."0");}$r[]=$r[0];print_r($r);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcrBCgIhGATge08RPx60ZHGXOtnSKXqBbiIiS8u6iMqvBRE9u8lehhnmS0uql2ta0o6Y@@0xKgU9cDiB5grOrQ2gtaxzxKedFrqhvc3kzb4ElR4tov2Y2XlPBZ/iKxTavsNw7LlgciO5oMnJu0JBQLdGFxptqGuTyd9mWggtE7pQDFKCTNb6Bw)

Answer (score 2):

### Clojure, 91 bytes

```
#(for[h[(/ 2)]i(range(- h)(count %)h)](for[j(range(- h)(count(% 0))h)](get(get % i[])j 0)))
```

Iterates over ranges in half-steps.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 33 bytes

```
{map {0,|$_,0},0 xx$_,|$_,0 xx$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OjexQKHaQKdGJV7HoFbHQKGiAsgC88DM2v/WCsWJlQppGho2hgomdjoKNqYKRnaamv8B)

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>73</s> 72 bytes

```js
a=>(g=a=>(r=[b],a.map(v=>r.push(v,b)),b=0,r))(a,b=a[0].map(_=>0)).map(g)
```

#### Formatted and commented

Inserting zeros horizontally and vertically are very similar operations. The idea here is to use the same function **g()** for both steps.

```js
a =>                            // a = input array
  (g = a =>                     // g = function that takes an array 'a',
    (                           //     builds a new array 'r' where
      r = [b],                  //     'b' is inserted at the beginning
      a.map(v => r.push(v, b)), //     and every two positions,
      b = 0,                    //     sets b = 0 for the next calls
      r                         //     and returns this new array
  ))(a, b = a[0].map(_ => 0))   // we first call 'g' on 'a' with b = row of zeros
  .map(g)                       // we then call 'g' on each row of the new array with b = 0
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

a=>(g=a=>(r=[b],a.map(v=>r.push(v,b)),b=0,r))(a,b=a[0].map(_=>0)).map(g)

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([
  [1]
])))

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([
  [1, 4],
  [5, 2]
])))

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([
  [1, 4, 7]
])))

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([
  [6],
  [4],
  [2]
])))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>183</s> <s>166</s> <s>162</s> <s>129</s> 119 bytes

```java
m->{int a=m.length,b=m[0].length,i=a*b,r[][]=new int[a-~a][b-~b];for(;i-->0;)r[i/b*2+1][i%b*2+1]=m[i/b][i%b];return r;}
```

Input and output as a `int[][]`.

-33 bytes by creating a port of [*@auhmaan*'s C# answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128616/52210).
-10 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##tVDLboMwELznK/ZSCVLjJlEfB4tI/YDmkt6QD2twUlMwyJhUEXJ@nRoo6qWReolkSzuz3tkZ53jCqKqlzrPPXpV1ZSzknqOtVQV9NQbPDVukBTYNvKHS3QJAaSvNAVMJuwGORMITDmkwVxgy33H@@tNYtCqFHWiIoS@jbeefAcYlLaQ@2g8i4jJZ8RmpGJeCmEEn1vJrVMfogjwR0UVwdqhMwFQUbVcsNIl6EMvN/Zon6m4qvJbnRsyZkbY1GgxzPZvM1K0ovJkfT6dKZVD6XMHeGqWPo/Up1P7cWFnSqrW09i1b6GD6DppJWb9X00CgaRrMLr3jrls7F4Zj/D81rnf@p04eHemeyObWW8jLTTc8@xRDkt8cbuH6bw)

```java
m->{                             // Method with integer-matrix as both parameter & return
  int a=m.length,                //  Set `a` to the input-height
      b=m[0].length,             //  Set `b` to the input-width
      i=a*b,                     //  Index integer, starting at `a*b`
      r[][]=new int[a-~a][b-~b]; //  Result integer-matrix with dimensions a*a+1 by b*b+1
  for(;i-->0;)                   //  Loop `i` in the range (a*b, 0] (so over each cell):
    r[i/b*2+1][i%b*2+1]=         //   Fill the current cell of the result-matrix:
      m[i/b][i%b];               //    With the correct input-integers
  return r;}                     //  Return result integer-matrix
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 49 bytes

```
Ａ⪪θ;αＡ””βＦ⁺¹×²Ｌ§α⁰Ａ⁺β⁰βＡ⁺β¶βＦα«βＡ0δＦιＡ⁺δ⁺κ⁰δ⁺δ¶»β
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9noWPVq06t8P63EYQs2EuEJ3b9H7PskeNuw7tPDz9EJC95tDycxsfNW4AKWjcdW4TkAlSAuEc2gZWfm7jodVgQYNzW0DcnVD5LSBiF0gHmLXl0LZDu89t@v/f0MTc2szECAA)

The input is a single string separating the rows with a semicolon.

Comment: Modern Charcoal can do this in 24 bytes: `≔Ｅ⪪θ;⪫00⪫ι0θＦθ⟦⭆ι0ι⟧⭆⊟θ0` but even avoiding StringMap I still think this can be done in 27 bytes.

Comment: Oh, and a couple of general tips: there's a predefined variable for the empty string, and you can create a string of zeros of a given length using Times or Mold.

Answer (score 2):

## C++17 + Modules, 192 bytes

Input as rows of strings from *cin*, Output to *cout*

```
import std.core;int main(){using namespace std;int i;auto&x=cout;string s;while(getline(cin,s)){for(int j=i=s.length()*2+1;j--;)x<<0;x<<'\n';for(auto c:s)x<<'0'<<c;x<<"0\n";}for(;i--;)x<<'0';}
```

Answer (score 2):

### [C#](http://csharppad.com/gist/dabea5dee31d5aeab869e01f65b95f7a), 146 bytes

---

#### Data

- **Input** `Int32[,]` `m` The matrix to be exploded
- **Output** `Int32[,]` The exploded matrix

---

#### Golfed

```cs
(int[,] m)=>{int X=m.GetLength(0),Y=m.GetLength(1),x,y;var n=new int[X*2+1,Y*2+1];for(x=0;x<X;x++)for(y=0;y<Y;y++)n[x*2+1,y*2+1]=m[x,y];return n;}
```

---

#### Ungolfed

```cs
( int[,] m ) => {
    int
        X = m.GetLength( 0 ),
        Y = m.GetLength( 1 ),
        x, y;
    
    var
        n = new int[ X * 2 + 1, Y * 2 + 1 ];
    
    for( x = 0; x < X; x++ )
        for( y = 0; y < Y; y++ )
            n[ x * 2 + 1, y * 2 + 1 ] = m[ x, y ];
    
    return n;
}
```

---

#### Ungolfed readable

```cs
// Takes an matrix of Int32 objects
( int[,] m ) => {
    // To lessen the byte count, store the matrix size
    int
        X = m.GetLength( 0 ),
        Y = m.GetLength( 1 ),
        x, y;
    
    // Create the new matrix, with the new size
    var
        n = new int[ X * 2 + 1, Y * 2 + 1 ];
    
    // Cycle through the matrix, and fill the spots
    for( x = 0; x < X; x++ )
        for( y = 0; y < Y; y++ )
            n[ x * 2 + 1, y * 2 + 1 ] = m[ x, y ];
    
    // Return the exploded matrix
    return n;
}
```

---

#### Full code

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestBench {
    public static class Program {
        private static Func<Int32[,], Int32[,]> f = ( int[,] m ) => {
            int
                X = m.GetLength( 0 ),
                Y = m.GetLength( 1 ),
                x, y,

                a = X * 2 + 1,
                b = Y * 2 + 1;

            var
                n = new int[ a, b ];

            for( x = 0; x < X; x++ )
                for( y = 0; y < Y; y++ )
                    n[ a, b ] = m[ x, y ];

            return n;
        };

        public static Int32[,] Run( Int32[,] matrix ) {
            Int32[,]
                result = f( matrix );

            Console.WriteLine( "Input" );
            PrintMatrix( matrix );

            Console.WriteLine( "Output" );
            PrintMatrix( result );

            Console.WriteLine("\n\n");

            return result;
        }

        public static void RunTests() {
            Run( new int[,] { { 1 } } );
            Run( new int[,] { { 1, 3, 5 } } );
            Run( new int[,] { { 1 }, { 3 }, { 5 } } );
            Run( new int[,] { { 1, 3, 5 }, { 1, 3, 5 }, { 1, 3, 5 } } );
        }
        
        static void Main( string[] args ) {
            RunTests();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void PrintMatrix<TSource>( TSource[,] array ) {
            PrintMatrix( array, o => o.ToString() );
        }
        public static void PrintMatrix<TSource>( TSource[,] array, Func<TSource, String> valueFetcher ) {
            List<String>
                output = new List<String>();

            for( Int32 xIndex = 0; xIndex < array.GetLength( 0 ); xIndex++ ) {
                List<String>
                    inner = new List<String>();

                for( Int32 yIndex = 0; yIndex < array.GetLength( 1 ); yIndex++ ) {
                    inner.Add( valueFetcher( array[ xIndex, yIndex ] ) );
                }

                output.Add( $"[ {String.Join( ", ", inner )} ]" );
            }

            Console.WriteLine( $"[\n   {String.Join( ",\n   ", output )}\n]" );
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Releases

- **v1.0** - `146 bytes` - Initial solution.

---

#### Notes

- None

Comment: You won't need the `(int[,] m)=>`, just `m=>` is enough if you state `m` is a 2D int-array int your answer. Also, you can change `,x,` to `,x=0,` and get rid of the `x=0` in the for-loop initialization for -1 byte. And you can remove `y++` from the inner loop by changing `=m[x,y];` to `=m[x,y++];` for an additional -1 byte. But +1 from me, and if I create a port of your answer it's also shorter than my current Java answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

## Dyalog APL, 24 bytes

```
{{⍵↑⍨¯1-⍴⍵}⊃⍪/,/2 2∘↑¨⍵}
```

Any improvements are welcome and wanted!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 92 bytes

```python
n=input()
a=[[0]*(2*len(n[0])+1)for i in[0]+2*n]
for l,v in zip(a[1::2],n):l[1::2]=v
print a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYm9CoAgEIB3n8JRzSGtSfBJjhscig7kkrCgXt6Mtu@n3HXb2bfGkbicVWmRIsCIRnmTF1bcWQ9Or/shSdKngzeM4gvZXj3Jh4pK4ELwaFmH/GO8RDmIq0ytATjbJ0x2RnwB)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>80</s> 78 bytes

```
a=>[...a,...a,a[0]].map((b,i)=>[...b,...b,0].map((_,j)=>i&j&1&&a[i>>1][j>>1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), 87 bytes

```python
from numpy import*
def f(a):b=zeros((2*len(a)+1,2*len(a[0])+1));b[1::2,1::2]=a;return b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzLCsMgFETX9StcanoXTfoIGPwSuQulSgP1wa1ZpD9vDXQznDkMU/b6yunaWqAcedpi2fkaS6Y6sKcPPAgrldNfT/kjxDS8fermPMIfzQV7k3JxZlRqgiNQ24V83Shx16w27GT6Hu4InWa4wQMZskJrquL4l@0H)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 13 bytes

```
uCm+0s,R0dG2Q
```

[Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=uCm%2B0s%2CR0dG2Q&input=%5B%5B1%2C+2%5D%2C+%5B3%2C+4%5D%5D&debug=0)

Another 13:

```
uC.iL+0m0dG2Q
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 22 bytes

Prompts for matrix, returns enclosed matrix.

```apl
{⍺⍀⍵\a}/⍴∘0 1¨1+2×⍴a←⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKPdtaIgJz8l9X/1o95dj3obHvVujUms1X/Uu@VRxwwDBcNDKwy1jQ5PB/ITH7VNeNQ3FaTnv2ZyfkGlQnFiTglXdW1qXmJSTmqwo08IVyxQTVJ@hUJ@noJuWl6xbX4eF5cCGECt4XrUu8oQXahtooahgommhqmCkSaG8k6QDgUTBXNMg8yAwkYA)

`a←⎕` prompt for matrix and assign to *a*

`⍴` the dimensions of *a* (rows, columns)

`2×` multiply by two

`1+` add one

`⍴∘0 1¨` use each to **r**eshape (cyclically) the numbers zero and one

`{`…`}/` reduce by inserting the following anonymous function between the two numbers:

`⍵\a` expand* the columns of *a* according to the right argument

`⍺⍀a` expand* the rows of that according to the left argument

* 0 inserts a column/row of zeros, 1 inserts an original data column/row

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 24 bytes

```
0,.0,[:,./^:2(0,.~,&0)"0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03B1krBQEfPQCfaSkdPP87KSAPIq9NRM9BUMuDiSk3OyFdIUzBUMFZQAZImCub//wMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 22 bytes

```
"vy0ý0.ø})"©.V€Sø®.Vø»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fqazS4PBeA73DO2o1lQ6t1At71LQm@PCOQ@v0woDk7v//o6MNY3WiTWNjAQ)

---

Actually uses the same piece of code 2x, so I can store it as a string and use Eval for -10 bytes.

Comment: You can save some bytes by using a `2F` list instead of your string with `.V`: [14 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyK2s0uDwXgO9wztqNR81rQk@vOP//@how1idaNPYWAA) (or [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyK2s0uDwXgO9wztqNR81rQkG0l6Hdv//Hx1tGKsTbRobCwA) matching your current pretty-printed output). Although I did just post [an alternative 8-byter approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198560/52210). :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 92 bytes

```python
def n(a):
	l,g='0 ',len(a[0])*2+1;print l*g
	for i in a:print l+' 0 '.join(i)+' 0';print l*g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU5LCoMwFFybU7zdSzQUlX5A8SQhoFBNUzRKcJGePk00ULqaDzPMbJ/9tZra@@c4gaEDa0g2c9VhCcjnMTiilCyvi6rdrDY7zLki2bRa0KANDE1yC4TQuLxXbahmUeGv4F0nhMAKpeQHcrxioHgLrP5zOT6Svh@JMxczksTVJa7awaiRxneOsfSgd2KRfRusgOzc9l8)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>11</s> 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
2Fε€0Ć}ø
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyO3c1kdNawyOtNUe3vH/f3S0oY5JrE60qY5RbCwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaBkX6nDpeRfWgLh6VT@N3I7t/VR0xqDI221h3f8r7XlUgooSi0pqdQtKMrMK0lNAak6tFvn0Db7/9HR0YaxsToKQErHJFYn2lTHCM7VMYcwzYDiIDmgTCwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
2F      # Loop 2 times:
  ε     #  Map each row of the matrix to:
        #  (which uses the (implicit) input-matrix in the first iteration)
   €0   #   Add a leading 0 before each item in the list
     Ć  #   Enclose the list, appending its own first item (to add a trailing 0 as well)
  }ø    #  After the map: zip/transpose; swapping rows/column
        # (after the loop, the result is output implicitly)
```